# What is the difference between Step in, Step out and Step Over?

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-code, step-into

I'm doing a project in which I used Debugging using visual studio code. I need some clear differences between **Step in, Step out and Step Over**. I saw vs code debugging documentation but it has no such details related to these. Anyone have idea ?

Comment: The documentation describes them under [Debug actions](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging#_debug-actions). (I guess it was updated after you looked at it.)

Answer (score 122, accepted):

**Step in:** means that if there is a function call, it goes inside the function and you can see how the function is executing line by line till it returns and you go back to the next line right after the function call.

**Step over:** means that if there is a function call, it just executes it like a black box and returns the result, but you cannot see how the function was executed.

**Step out:** means that if you have **Stepped in** a function and now you want to skip seeing how the rest of the function is going to execute, you **Step out** and the function returns. Then, you go back to the next line, that is the line right after the function call.

Comment: Doesn't "Step out" also neglect to execute any remaining instructions in the function? It would be nice to update these descriptions to adress where any instructions are omitted.

Comment: @stack-delay No instructions are ever omitted AFAIK. You can test that really easily: debug a function with two prints and step out before the second one, and you'll see it still prints.